# How to check if URL is available or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to check if URL is available or not. I am using the below Javascript code to verify this but it works for only HTTP URLs. If the URL is HTTPS it fails and I get the error `alert`.

```
var backendUrl = "https://myserver:8081/app/test.jsp";
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: backendUrl
}).done(function (result) {
    console.log("working");
    window.location.href = backendUrl;
}).fail(function () {
    alert(Sorry URL is not access able");
});
```

Can someone tell me a reason and some more precise way to check if URL is available or not using javascript.

Comment: Use a relative path. When making an AJAX request the receiving domain must match the requesting one exactly - down to the port number. You can confirm the exact reason for failure by checking the console after making the request

Comment: It's most likely a security issue, look in the console.  I've a feeling you have not got a valid SSL for myserver:8081..

Comment: No https URL is can be open from browser.

Comment: Assuming your URL is not the same domain/port as the page you're on, you'll probably need to do this from your web server, instead of from the browser - so it'll depend on what server technology you've got for your web application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I use to check if a URL exists:

```
function UrlExists(url, cb) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'text',
        type: 'GET',
        complete: function (xhr) {
            if (typeof cb === 'function')
                cb.apply(this, [xhr.status]);
        }
    });
}

UrlExists('-- Insert Url Here --', function (status) {
    if (status === 200) {
        // Execute code if successful
    } else if (status === 404) {
        // Execute code if not successful
    } else {
        // Execute code if status doesn't match above
    }
});
```

There are many status codes so you can change out the 404 to whatever code you want to match or just put the code you want to execute in the last else case and that code will execute if the status does not match any of the requested status codes.

Comment: what would you return if the status code is not 200 nor 404?  I think you could have an else to handle all other scenarios

Comment: Yeah, this is just an example. The handling part can be edited to suite your specific needs

Comment: Obvious to me (and you) but perhaps not for others (still, I think it should be able to handle other status codes)

Comment: I edited it to include the else and with a description too.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use a relative path?

e.g app/test.jsp - https://myserver:8081/app/test.jsp

```
            var backendUrl = "app/test.jsp";
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: backendUrl
            }).done(function (result) {
                console.log("working");
                window.location.href = backendUrl;
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("Sorry URL is not access able");
             });
```

If you're running on a local environment it's unlikely that you would have an SSL installed.

Comment: No there is no SSL issue as i can open this URL from browser.. Well i have a requirement that a URL should be like this along with port so i cant use relative path..